# Open folder on button click and get path of the folder in xamarin forms andorid

Tags: c#, xaml

I want to select folder for save an image in forms android, Please anyone help me how to achive this.

I have done this by using the follwing method

```
public string  OpenFolder()
    {
        activity = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context as MainActivity;
        activity.Intent = new Intent();
        activity.Intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionOpenDocumentTree);
        activity.StartActivityForResult(activity.Intent, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_DIRECTORY);
        return RealPath;
    }
```

After selecting Folder we can easily get the path.

```
 activity.ActivityResult += (object sender, ActivityResultEventArgs e) =>
        {
            FolderPath = e.Intent.Data;
            string DummyPath=FolderPath.Path;
            OriginalPath = DummyPath.Split(':')[1];
            RealPath = "/storage/emulated/0/" + OriginalPath;      
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Right i think your asking how to select a folder?

This should point you in the right direction

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/android5.0/DirectorySelection